# Oracle LIKE condition with year information

Tags: sql, oracle, matching, sql-like, check-constraints

I have a table containing two attributes with year information (as numbers)

```
DateOfBirth   Number(4)   NULL,
DateDeceased  Number(4)   NULL,
```

I also made a check constraint to make sure the date is correct like this:

```
CONSTRAINT BirthValueCheck    CHECK (DateOfBirth < DateDeceased),
CONSTRAINT ValidBirthYear     CHECK (DateOfBirth LIKE '[1 - 2] [0 - 9] [0 - 9] [0 - 9]'),
CONSTRAINT ValidDeathYear     CHECK (DateDeceased LIKE '[1 - 2] [0 - 9] [0 - 9] [0 - 9]')
```

When I insert a new value into the table like this:

```
INSERT INTO ARTIST(ArtistID, LastName, FirstName, Nationality, DateOfBirth, DateDeceased)
VALUES(SEQ_ARTISTID.NEXTVAL, 'Miro', 'Joan', 'Spanish', '1893', '1983');
```

I get an error saying:

```
Error starting at line : 104 in command -
INSERT INTO ARTIST(ArtistID, LastName, FirstName, Nationality, DateOfBirth, DateDeceased)
VALUES(SEQ_ARTISTID.NEXTVAL, 'Miro', 'Joan', 'Spanish', '1893', '1983')
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02290: CHECK-beperking (DBI279057.VALIDDEATHYEAR) is geschonden.
02290. 00000 -  "check constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    The values being inserted do not satisfy the named check

*Action:   do not insert values that violate the constraint.
```

I don't get why it gives me this error, since 1983 seems valid with the constraint given. Also it doesn't give me an error with the DateOfBirth check constraint, which is basically the same constraint and is declared before the ValidDeathYear constraint. Is this some kind of bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `LIKE` operator does not support this "regular expression" syntax that you are using. `LIKE` only supports two types of wildcards: a single character `_` or multiple characters `%`. It also does not support ranges or "minimum" length values.

Plus: you should not use `LIKE` on a number. `LIKE` is for strings (`varchar`, `char`)

If you want to constrain the range of years, you need to use something like this:

```
CONSTRAINT ValidBirthYear     CHECK (DateOfBirth between 1900 and 2100)
```

As the column is defined as `number` you can't store non-numeric values in it anyway.

Comment: 's solution definitely works, but if you want to use regular expression syntax as in your question, you can use Oracle's `REGEXP_LIKE()` function, e.g.:
`CONSTRAINT ValidBirthYear CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE( DateOfBirth, '^[12][0-9]{3}$' ) )`

The accepted answer is definitely better than using `REGEXP_LIKE()` though as it uses numbers and avoids any weird entries like '2999'.